# cout binary data

Tags: c++

If this snippet of code saves an an object/image to file. What would need to be modified for it to actually `cout` the image's binary data stream? Thanks!

```
if (frame && frame->Contains(ID3FN_DATA))
  {
    cout << "*** extracting picture to file \"" << argv[2] << "\"...";
    frame->Field(ID3FN_DATA).ToFile(argv[2]);
    cout << "done" << endl;
  }
```

Comment: What library are you using?  The answer will be specific to that library, since this isn't part of the C++ spec.

Comment: @templatetypedef, It's from ID3lib and I just want to instead of this: `frame->Field(ID3FN_DATA).ToFile(argv[2]);` send `frame->Field(ID3FN_DATA)` to `cout`

Comment: You can't, at least not portably:  `std::cout` is a text stream and [there is no portable way to reopen it as a binary stream.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.13)  What, exactly, are you trying to do?  It usually doesn't make a whole lot of sense to dump a bunch of binary data out to the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this library particularly, but the documentation on the website suggests that that once you have the `ID3_Field` object, you can get its raw binary size using [ID3_Field::BinSize()](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/api/class_i_d3___field.html#a2) and the raw bytes from [ID3_Field::GetRawBinary()](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/api/class_i_d3___field.html#a23).  Once you have these two parameters, you can write the binary data to any `ostream`, including `cout`, by calling

```
myOStream.write((char *)field->GetRawBinary(), field->BinSize());
```

I have no idea if this is going to work because I've never used this library, but at least intuitively this makes sense.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is my understanding that this won't work:  because `std::cout` is a text stream, `std::ostream::write` will perform newline translation.

Comment: @James McNellis- What if the output was to a stream other than `cout`?  Would it work then?  And if that won't work, is there any hope for doing this in a cross-platform way?

Comment: It will work if it's a binary stream, but as I noted in a comment to the original post, there's no portable way to reopen `std::cout` as a binary stream.